# Can oxygen gas in air react with Mn3O4 to form MnO2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, reference-request, catalysis

I think $\ce{MnO2}$ at high temperature can be used as a catalyst for $\ce{SO2 + O2 -> SO3}$:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{MnO2 + SO2 &-> MnSO4}\tag{1}\\
\ce{3 MnSO4 &-> Mn3O4 + SO2 + 2 SO3}\tag{2}\\
\ce{Mn3O4 + O2 &-> 3 MnO2}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

I think the first two reactions are possible, but I don't know about the third one.

Comment: Intuitively, I suspect rather $\ce{Mn2O3},$ not $\ce{MnO2}.$ And yes, two first reactions look OK to me except you probably should've mentioned the temperatures.

Comment: $\ce{Mn2O3 -> Mn3O4}$ reaction has been discussed here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/121339/how-to-convert-mn2o3-to-mn3o4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manganese(IV) oxide decomposes around 500 °C ([German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangan(IV)-oxid#Eigenschaften) lists $\pu{450 °C},$ [1, p. 396] lists $\pu{530–585 °C}):$

$$\ce{4 MnO2 ->[\sim\pu{500 °C}] 2 Mn2O3 + O2}\label{rxn:1}\tag{R1}$$

On the other hand, according to [2, p. 12], $\ce{Mn3O4}$ reacts with oxygen only above $\pu{500 °C}$ and forms manganese(III) oxide:

$$\ce{4 Mn3O4 + O2 ->[>\pu{500 °C}] 6 Mn2O3}\label{rxn:2}\tag{R2}$$

Upon further heating, the reaction in the opposite direction takes place [1, p. 396]:

$$\ce{6 Mn2O3 ->[>\pu{940–1090 °C}] 4 Mn3O4 + O2}\label{rxn:3}\tag{R3}$$

All in all, the third reaction you've proposed $(\ce{Mn3O4 + O2 -> 3 MnO2})$ is unlikely to occur and the product will be $\ce{Mn2O3},$ which unfortunately would break the catalytic cycle.

As for the first two reactions, they are described in the literature all right [1, pp. 397, 399]:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{MnO2 + SO2 &->[\pu{450 °C}] MnSO4}\tag{1}\\
\ce{3 MnSO4 &->[\pu{850–1155 °C}] Mn3O4 + SO2 + 2 SO3}\tag{2}\\
\end{align}
$$

Reactions \eqref{rxn:1}–\eqref{rxn:3} are also described in Greenwood's *Chemistry of the elements*: [3, pp. 1048–1049]:

> It is $\ce{MnO2},$ however, which is by far the most important oxide in this group, though it is not the most stable oxide of manganese, decomposing to $\ce{Mn2O3}$ above about $\pu{530 °C}$ and being a useful oxidizing agent. […]
>
> $\ce{Mn3O4}$ is formed when any oxide of manganese is heated to about $\pu{1000 °C}$ in air […].
>
> If $\ce{MnO2}$ is heated less strongly (say $,\pu{800 °C})$ than is required to produce $\ce{Mn3O4},$ then the more stable α-form of $\ce{Mn2O3}$ results […].

#### References

1. R. A. Lidin, V. A. Molochko, and L. L. Andreeva, *Reactivity of Inorganic Substances*, 3rd ed.; Khimia: Moscow, **2000**. (in Russian)
2. Turova, N. *Inorganic Chemistry in Tables*; Springer: Heidelberg ; New York, **2011**. ISBN 978-3-642-20486-9
3. Greenwood, N. N.; Earnshaw, A. *Chemistry of the Elements*, 2nd ed.; Butterworth-Heinemann: Oxford; Boston, **1997**. ISBN 978-0-7506-3365-9.